# How to attach source of com.sun.script.javascript for debugging RhinoScriptEngine in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, rhino, java

I would like to debug RhinoScriptEngine in com.sun.script.javascript package.
to see the source code i attach the openJDK openjdk-6-src-b25-01_may_2012.
but when i try to step into any method of e.g. RhinoScriptEngine or ScriptEngineManager it doesn't work...
eclipse opens the corresponding class, but the debugger doesn't step through the source code

how to fix this and debug RhinoScriptEngine and Rhino itself?

Answer (score 0):

even in the jdks, the rt.jar file might have been compiled without debugging enabled.
Have you checked if the RhinoScriptEngine class has a `LineNumberTable` and a `LocalVariableTable`?

In my case the jdk and jre is at least compiled with the `LineNumberTable`.
So I can step through jdk classes and can see the values of fields and arguments but not of local variables.

You can use javap to disassemble a class and see what information are actually provided, e.g.

```
javap -v -cp rt.jar com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine
```

But I didn't actually try to debug the RhinoScriptEngine class since my jdk doesn't have a source attachment for the RhinoScriptEngine file and the openjdk I found does not have it at all. I assume it belongs to the proprietary part of java.